# DirectX Font not drawing?

Tags: c++, text, fonts, directx, game-engine

I am making a game in DirectX, C++ with different parts of it being in classes. Currently I am doing a font class but when I go to draw a string it is not displayed and I have no idea why. Any help is very much appreciated.

font.h

```
class d2Font
{
public:
    d2Font(void);
    ~d2Font(void);

    void Create(string name, int size, LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 device);
    void Draw(string text, int x, int y, int width, int height, DWORD format = DT_LEFT, D3DCOLOR colour = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255));

private:
    LPD3DXFONT font;
};
```

font.cpp

```
d2Font::d2Font(void)
{
font = NULL;
}

d2Font::~d2Font(void)
{
if(font)
    font->Release();
}

void d2Font::Create(string name, int size, LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 device)
{
LPD3DXFONT tempFont = NULL;
D3DXFONT_DESC desc = {
    size,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    false,
    DEFAULT_CHARSET,
    OUT_TT_PRECIS,
    CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
    DEFAULT_PITCH,
    (char)name.c_str()
};
D3DXCreateFontIndirect(device, &desc, &tempFont);

font = tempFont;
}

void d2Font::Draw(string text, int x, int y, int width, int height, DWORD format, D3DCOLOR colour)
{
RECT rect = {x, y, width, height};
//SetRect(&rect, x, y, width, height);

font->DrawText(NULL, text.c_str(), -1, &rect, format, colour);
}
```

EDIT:
Here is the code in main.cpp

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
gameHinstance = hInstance;

gameMain = new d2Main();
testFont = new d2Font();

if(!gameMain->NewWindow(hInstance, hWnd, "Test Game", 800, 400, nCmdShow, false))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Error! Unable to create window!", "D2EX", MB_OK | MB_ICONASTERISK);
    return 0;
}

gameMain->GameRunning = true;

testFont->Create("Arial", 12, gameMain->dx->d3ddev);

gameMain->GameLoop();

return 0;
}

void d2Main::GameUpdate()
{
gameMain->dx->d3ddev->BeginScene();
testFont->Draw("HelloWorld!", 10, 10, 200, 30, DT_LEFT, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0));
gameMain->dx->d3ddev->EndScene();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are obviously some wrong fields in the font descriptor. One is the weight, as mentioned by Roger Rowland. Another is the last one, FaceName (the font name). You're trying to cast a pointer to a char, which will give bad results. If your project is configured to use Unicode (the default for most project types in Visual Studio), the FaceName member will be an array of WCHARs, so you should use wstring. The other thing is that you should check the return value of D3DXCreateFontIndirect (as well as any other D3D functions and methods that return an HRESULT):

```
HRESULT d2Font::Create(const wstring& name, int size, LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 device)
{
    D3DXFONT_DESC desc = {
        size,
        0,
        400,
        0,
        false,
        DEFAULT_CHARSET,
        OUT_TT_PRECIS,
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
        DEFAULT_PITCH
    };

    wcscpy_s(desc.FaceName, LF_FACESIZE, name.c_str());

    HRESULT hr = D3DXCreateFontIndirect(device, &desc, &font);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I am using a multi byte character set and therefore this does not work. With my current version I checked the HRESULT and it is all ok.

Comment: @OnlyAntony So use **string** and mbscpy_s instead of wcscpy_s.

Comment: Sorry, this is not working. I have included the <mbstring.h> and then use: _mbscpy_s(desc.FaceName, LF_FACESIZE, name.c_str()); and I have tried the desc.Filename & name witha & before it and also removed the c._str() from the name. The error it shows is: error C2664: 'errno_t _mbscpy_s(unsigned char *,size_t,const unsigned char *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CHAR [32]' to 'unsigned char *'

Comment: In that case you can just cast the arguments to unsigned char: `_mbscpy_s((unsigned char*)desc.FaceName, LF_FACESIZE, (unsigned char*)name.c_str());`

Comment: I have tried the above but it is still not working. So I shall start again, so thanks for your help.

Comment: I have now fixed it without restarting. I forgot to add the d3dddevice->Present after the end scene.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you specified a zero for font weight. Try something like this

```
D3DXFONT_DESC desc = {
size,
    0,
    0,
    400,
    false,
    DEFAULT_CHARSET,
    OUT_TT_PRECIS,
    CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
    DEFAULT_PITCH,
    (char)name.c_str()
};
```